# Javafx limiting drag within window

Tags: java, javafx

I am making an app that has a draggable background, everything is work correctly, I can drag, but I have noticed that, I can drag past my window and my scene will re-structure and allow me to drag as far as I want in a given direction, here is a snippet to show what I mean [Normal before dragging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELCin.png)
[After dragging to far bottom right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiBLj.png) As noticed the scene has allowed the imageview to go as far as the mouse takes it, how can i limit it to stay within the window?
Here is my code

```
 this.imgAdvertising.setOnMousePressed(e -> {

      dragDelta.x = this.imgAdvertising.getLayoutX() - e.getSceneX();
      dragDelta.y = this.imgAdvertising.getLayoutY() - e.getSceneY();
 });


this.imgAdvertising.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {

    double x = e.getSceneX() + dragDelta.x;
    double y = e.getSceneY() + dragDelta.y;
    this.imgAdvertising.setLayoutX(e.getSceneX() + dragDelta.x);
    this.imgAdvertising.setLayoutY(e.getSceneY() + dragDelta.y);
});
```

Comment: i'd suggest you test x+ImageWidth and y+ImageHeight is less than the window height and width before you update the position of imgAdvertising. Tell me if this gives you an idea

Comment: I have tried but its not worked

Comment: Can you edit your answer to see what you tried please ?

Comment: I basically put this in the ondrag method  `
                if(dragDelta.x + this.imgAdvertising.getFitWidth() > this.imgAdvertising.getScene().getWidth())
                    System.out.println("Drag is greater than Scene "+dragDelta.x + this.imgAdvertising.getFitWidth());
                else
                    System.out.println("Drag is less than Scene "+dragDelta.x + this.imgAdvertising.getFitWidth());
               `

Comment: and the output is ?

Comment: it prints drag greater at times, but not very accurate

Comment: print all these in onMouseDragged : x,y,dragDelta.x, dragDelta.y, e.getSceneX(), e.getSceneY(), check these values